# Murder, she emailed

Tags: phrases, etymology

You might know the phrase template from the crime comedy series "Murder, She Wrote" with Angela Lansbury, but before that there was the "Miss Marple" film "Murder, She Said". But that can't be the origin either, as I recently saw an even older (1945) "Private Snafu" cartoon named "It's Murder, She Says" ("she" here is a hawt gnat - it's a malaria prevention film).

Quite obviously, it's neigh impossible to google the real origin of the phrase "Murder, She (verbed)" due to too much interference. Can you help?

Comment: Hi Hauke.  Your request is bit off topic for this group.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off topic

Comment: From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder,_She_Wrote) *The title [of the TV series **Murder, She Wrote**] comes from **Murder, She Said**, which was the title of a 1961 film adaptation of Agatha Christie's Miss Marple novel **4:50 from Paddington**.* I don't suppose the collocation ***Murder, She Said*** had any particular currency or "non-literal" significance before being used as the title of that movie.

Comment: I suspect this would be better suited to a TV or literature SE, or maybe English Language and Usage.